# Android how to pick up images from Lollipop / Marshmallow and save it on imageView?

Tags: android, android-intent

1. I tried that code and gave me error unable to decode stream `filenotfoundException`. So I found that the latest versions of Android Marshmallow and lollipop doesn't have the gallery application and the images uploaded to a server.

   ```
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
               // just some safety built in 
               if( uri == null ) {
                   // TODO perform some logging or show user feedback
                   return null;
               }
               // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
               // this will only work for images selected from gallery
               String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
               Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
               if( cursor != null ){
                   int column_index = cursor
                   .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                   cursor.moveToFirst();
                   String picturePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                   return picturePath;

               }
               // this is our fallback here
               return uri.getPath();
       }

           public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
               if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                       Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                       selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
               imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getPath(selectedImageUri)));

                   }
               }
           }
   ```
2. My intent code:

   ```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Get rid of `getPath()`.

Step #2: Use an [image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso). Pass it the `Uri` you get from the `Intent` passed into `onActivityResult()`, and your `ImageView`. It will handle loading the image into the `ImageView` for you.

If you would prefer to load the image yourself, you will need to:

- Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` for the data represented by the `Uri`
- Use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to load the data off the `InputStream` and decode it into a `Bitmap`
- Do the above steps in a background thread, so you do not tie up the main application thread while doing that I/O (e.g., `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`)
- When the `Bitmap` is ready, put it in the `ImageView` while running on the main application thread (e.g., `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask`)